# Вывод произвольного типа записей в категории

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Создала произвольный тип записи и к нему таксономию. Создала новые записи, раскинула их по категориям, но когда захожу в категории, вижу что во всех категориях отображаются сразу все записи. Записи не разбиваются на категории. Подскажите, что не так в коде. Вот код из файла категории (`taxonomy-courses_cat.php`):

```
<?php 
// задаем нужные нам критерии выборки данных из БД

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'courses',
'order' => 'ASC',
'orderby' => 'menu_order'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Цикл
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();?>

                <div class="cours_cat_main">
                    <div class="cours_cat_title">
                        <div class="cours_cat_title_text"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php 
    }
} else {
    // Постов не найдено
}
// Возвращаем оригинальные данные поста. Сбрасываем $post.
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете новый запрос на странице, перекрывая им запрос по умолчанию для данной страницы. В вашем случае либо измените запрос на странице, добавив к нему параметр выбора по категории

```php
//Получаем объект текущей категории курсов
$term = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'courses',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
    'courses_cat' => $term->name
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Либо удалите вообще запрос со страницы, но если Вам нужно изменить (например сортировку) его используйте [pre_get_posts()](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/pre_get_posts). И данный вариант правильный.

Comment: Здравствуйте еще раз. Такой вопрос, делаю такой же функционал на другом сайте, и почему то пишет, что посты не найдены. Когда убираю строчку ' $term = get_queried_object(); ' только тогда показываются посты, но опять - все сразу. Не могу понять, почему на одном сайте все работает, на другом (полностью клон, разве что хостинги разные) нет.